# Don't install seleinum webdriver \validation.cc(7): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'v8.h'

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to install selenium webdriver javascript for windows 7. 
I install already:
-nodejs npm
-microsoft visual studio express 2010
-windows sdk
-vc compiler
-python
-java
But, when i run this command:
npm install selenium-webdriver -g
an error:

```
..\src\validation.cc(7): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'v8.h': N
o such file or directory [D:\Users\Артем\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\selen
ium-webdriver\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build\validation.vcxp
roj]
```

full listing:

```
D:\Windows\system32>npm install selenium-webdriver -g
/


> bufferutil@1.1.0 install D:\Users\Артем\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\selen
ium-webdriver\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild


D:\Users\Артем\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\node_modules\
ws\node_modules\bufferutil>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "D:\Program
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\
node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Построение проектов в этом решении по одному. Чтобы включить параллельное постро
ение, добавьте параметр "/m".
  bufferutil.cc
..\src\bufferutil.cc(7): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'v8.h': N
o such file or directory [D:\Users\Артем\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\selen
ium-webdriver\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074
:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Users\Артем\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\
node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok

> utf-8-validate@1.1.0 install D:\Users\Артем\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\s
elenium-webdriver\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Visual Studio do you have ? If it's 2012 you could do this :

npm config set msvs_version 2012

Or try this

npm install --save selenium-webdriver@2.44.0